# Counting most frequent character in a string

Tags: c, string, function

I have a complex `C` program, and i wanna write only a function which gets a string as a parameter.

```
int most_frequent(char *string)
```

The function has to return the number of the most frequent character in the string. I tried something like this, but this is incorrect i think:

```
 int most_frequent(char *string){
     int i, lenght;
     lenght=strlen(string);
     int max=0, x=0;
     for(i=0;i<lenght;i++)
     {
         if(string[i]==string[i++])
         {
             x++;
         }
         if(max<x)
             max=x;
     }
     return max;
 }
```

for example: "overflow" - 2
             "eleven" - 3

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong, your code is counting the most numbers that are the same that follow each other.

Comment: "to return the number of the most frequent character' needs a table of occurrence count for the various characters.  `if(string[i]==string[i++])` simple test if 2 subsequent `string[]` are the same.  You need a new approach.

Comment: first figure out how you would solve this problem without a computer, then try to write code.

Comment: You can either use a frequency table (as suggested by chux), or use two nested `for` loops. The outer loop chooses a character. The inner loop counts the occurrences of that character.

Comment: Try to count the frequency of each charachter and save it, then return the most higher number you get.
For example, for "overflow":
Count the number of 'o', then count the number of 'v', ...
at the end return the max number.

Comment: If an answer is really good, then `most_frequent("")` should return 1 as the _null character_ is part of the string.

Comment: Tip: you need 2 "for" to do this!

Comment: Beware a common pitfall to this task is assuming `string[i]` will not return a negative number.  Good answers handle that.  Although it would appear [@FirestormXYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3605220/firestormxyz) approach avoids that issue.

Comment: For all answers: `strlen()` inside the for loop is hardly optimal...

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers, i did it with your help! Big up!

Comment: @chux By the same logic strlen("") should return 1. But, no, the null character is part of the string structure, not part of the string value.

Comment: @TomBlodget Coding goal is "most frequent character in the string".  "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  §7.1.1 1. With that C definition of a _string_, I still maintain `most_frequent("")` should return 1.  On the other hand, you distinguish between _string structure_ and _string value_: a reasonable opinion.  Do you have something to show how C specifies that difference? Either way, such corner cases deserve explicit coding requirements to reduce problems.

Comment: @chux Nope. I just used my own words to describe a well-understood concept. I think comparison with `strlen("") == 0` is sufficient as an appeal to authority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have a string that follows ASCII. In this way, there are 256 possible values for each char. Thus we count the frequency of each and return the largest one.

```
int most_frequent(char *string){
     int count[256] = {0}; // Assum char is ASCII
     int max = 0;
     int i;

     for(i=0; i < strlen(string) ;i++) {
         count[(unsigned char)(string[i])] ++;
     }

     for(i=0; i < 256 ;i++) {
         if (count[i] > max) 
             max = count[i];
     }
     return max;
 }
```

Comment: The `(int)` cast does not prevent [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931538/counting-most-frequent-character-in-a-string-c#comment86879059_49931538) and serves little purpose.  A `(unsigned char)` cast would help.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers, i did it with your help! Big up!

Comment: ASCII is so hard to get right because of its limited usage and so much misinformation about it. It goes from 0 to 127. And, a more general assumption would be that each "character" is one `char`. So, instead of 256, use `UCHAR_MAX + 1` (including `<limits.h>`), which is consistent with your casting to `unsigned char`..

Answer (score 2):

Do following:

```
// version that ignores the upper and lower case
int most_frequent(char *string) {
    int letterCout[26];

    // counts occurrence of each letter 
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i){
       // this counts characters if you are ignoring the case (upper or lower)
       if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] =< 'z')
           alphabet [string[i] - 'a']++;
       else if (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] =< 'Z')
           alphabet [string[i] - 'A']++;
    }

    // finds which letter occurred the most
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i)
        if (letterCoutn[i] > max)
            max = letterCount[i];

    return max;
}
```

or you can do this:

```
// version which does not ignore case but count the separately
int most_frequent(char *string) {
    int letterCout[52];  // 52 so you can count upper and lower case

    // counts occurrence of each letter 
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i){
       if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z')
           alphabet [string[i] - 'a' + 26]++; // plus 26 so to offset in array so upper case could be counted in lower half of an array.
       else if (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z')
           alphabet [string[i] - 'A']++;
    }

    // finds which letter occurred the most
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string) * 2; ++i)
        if (letterCoutn[i] > max)
            max = letterCount[i];

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers, i did it with your help! Big up!